# How to get current location (Longitude and Latitude)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

Hello i need to get current coordinates when i start fragment (in onResume()). I try next:

```
public class FragmentNear extends Fragment implements  LocationListener{
View v;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView tvLess1;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near, null);

    tvLess1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_less_1);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.d("myLogs", "onChangeLocation");
//tvLess1.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
//Log.d("myLogs","Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("myLogs","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("myLogs","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("myLogs","status");
}
 }
```

It get coordinates for me about one minute, why it take so much time? And then onChangeLocation is calling all time, but i want update coordinates only in when onResume is calling? How can i do it?

---

SOLUTION IS to use next:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Are you inside a building?

Answer (score 0):

It takes so much time because you are using GPS

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

You device must have a valid signal from the GPS satelittes and this will take time depending on your environmental situation. In buildings it will take more time and outside it will be much faster as there is nothing blocking the straight line between your device and the satelittes.

The method "onLocationChange" is always called if there is a change in the current GPS location - Which will happen very often, as you device is moving or more satelittes are locked so your current location is tracked more precisely.

For making it faster you could try not using GPS: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Here is a list of possible other ways to get your current location - But this wont fix the continuously call of "onLocationChange" - This is normal behaviour. If you do not want to do anything in this method, just leave it empty.

Comment: Thank you, but can you show other way to get current location?

Comment: I do not have code that I can show, which will be short and understandable, but you can have a look at the MyLocationOverlay - I assume you are using GoogleMaps as your tags are saying - Then you can request the current location whenever you want to have it. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay This is how I did it in my app and it works very well, but as I already told, I cant show you short understandable code

Comment: But i use google maps v2, and i didn't use mapView. MyLocatonOVerlay(context ,Mapview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 4);
        gm.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
       Marker myMarker = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title("You are here") 

        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```